# C variable not where I expect to find it in memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Can someone explain why printing the pointers to the two ints results in them being placed in different locations in relation to the chars.

The piece of code below should print out the memory address from &a to &c which (I think) should include the two ints defined but it doesn't, however when I try to find out where they're stored in memory (see second code segment) it does print them between the two chars as expected.

Please explain why printing the int pointers effects the ints being stored between the chars in memory.

The two code samples are the same except code 2 has an extra line `printf("\n\n%p,%p\n",&i,&j);` which prints the pointers of the two ints.

<sub>Edit: Yes I know the prinf formating is ugly but the code was only to help me clarify how memory and pointers work, so I didn't need it to be pretty</sub>

Code1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv){
    char a='a';
    int i=1;
    int j=2;
    char c='c';
    char *pos;
    for ( pos=&c; pos<=&a; pos++ ){
        printf("%p\t",pos);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for ( pos=&c; pos<=&a; pos++ ){
        printf("%i\t\t",*pos);
    }
}
```

Results from Code1

```
0x7ffde6321e7e  0x7ffde6321e7f  
99              97
```

Code2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv){
    char a='a';
    int i=1;
    int j=2;
    char c='c';
    char *pos;
    for ( pos=&c; pos<=&a; pos++ ){
        printf("%p\t",pos);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for ( pos=&c; pos<=&a; pos++ ){
        printf("%i\t\t",*pos);
    }
    printf("\n\n%p,%p\n",&i,&j);
}
```

Results from Code2

```
0x7ffc3575616b  0x7ffc3575616c  0x7ffc3575616d  0x7ffc3575616e  0x7ffc3575616f  0x7ffc35756170  0x7ffc35756171  0x7ffc35756172  0x7ffc35756173  0x7ffc35756174  0x7ffc35756175  0x7ffc35756176  0x7ffc35756177  
99              2               0               0               0               1               0               0               0               -4              127             0               97              

0x7ffc35756170,0x7ffc3575616c
```

Comment: The first program never uses `i` and `j`, so the compiler simply ignored them.

Comment: Both of them are undefined behavior.

Comment: Try to compile your program to assembler code and you'll see what @Barmar said: the first program simply has **no** `int` varables `i` and `j` – the compiler found them unreferenced, so unnecessary, and removed them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're relying on something<sup>Note 1</sup> which is not specified in C standard. The behaviour cannot be defined. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).<sup>Note 2</sup>

That said, you should always cast the argument of `%p` to `void *`, as the expected type is `void *` and there's no default promotion for pointers.

---

**Note 1:**

C does not mention or guarantee the order of allocation of variables / objects in a program. There's no guarantee that they will have consecutive memory locations, either increasing or decreasing. They are purely allowed to have random memory locations, so the *theory* you're believing in,

```
 for ( pos=&c; pos<=&a; pos++ )
```

does not hold true. An(y) implementation can choose to place (*reorder*) variable(s) however it does see fit. There's absolutely **no guarantee** of the order of memory address with respect to their definition in the code.

---

**Note 2:**

For relational operators, quoting `C11`. chapter §6.5.8, (*emphasis mine*)

> When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the
>   address space of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object types both point to the
>   same object, or both point one past the last element of the same array object, they
>   compare equal. If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object,
>   pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members
>   declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript
>   values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values. All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. If the
>   expression `P` points to an element of an array object and the expression `Q` points to the
>   last element of the same array object, the pointer expression `Q+1` compares greater than
>   `P`. **In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.**

So, for your case, the comparison `pos<=&a;` is an attempt to compare two pointers which are neither

- pointing to same object
- members of the same aggregate object
- pointers to array elements
- pointers to members of the same union object

In short, they are not within the defined scope and hence, using them as operand of the relational operator invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The location of local variables is implementation defined.  The compiler may put them in any order it deems best.

Making seemingly unrelated code changes such as an extra print statement or changing the optimization level can change how the compiler lays out the variables.

In short, you can't depend on any particular layout of variables in memory.

Comment: Nitpicking: In the standard "implementation defined" means that the implementation must document what it does. Not so here.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are placed in the stack (or in register if possible & if their address is not referred). In your example the i is first and j is second local vars, so you have `push i, push j` - the address of the second `&j` is `&i-1`.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this may mislead people. There's no inherent "stack" defined in C.

Comment: Indeed - "The language does not define any storage allocation facility other than static definition and the stack discipline provided by the local variables of functions;" (The C Programming Language-Brian W. Kernighan, Dennis M. Ritchie)